# How do I combine grep and subset with piper

Tags: r

I am new to tidyverse. I have this clunky code that combines a lot of functions together

```
flow[grep(paste(paste(series, "J8","F", sep = "."), "TEMP",sep = "_")
                         , flow$Final.code), -1]
```

flow is a dataset.

is there a way for me to rewrite this code using piper so that it's easier to see?

Comment: It's hard to really help without a representative sample of data. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easier to help with. Also guessing that by "piper", you mean `magrittr`/`dplyr`-style pipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be:

```
flow %>%
  filter(str_detect(NAME_OF_-1_COLUMN, paste(paste(series, "J8","F", sep = "."), "TEMP", sep = "_")))
```

It's not entirely clear what your data is so I can't be sure this is a perfect solution. This doesn't work if you are using your grep command to reference row names. If you wanted to go full tidyverse, replace `paste()` with `str_c()`.

You can also assign the paste-ception to a variable and just use that if readability is the concern:

```
things_to_detect = paste(paste(series, "J8","F", sep = "."), "TEMP", sep = "_")

flow %>%
  filter(str_detect(NAME_OF_-1_COLUMN, things_to_detect))
```